# Trouble with Flot Graph of displaying temperature

Tags: php, jquery, flot

I am doing the temperature project needed to use flot to display the data. And I found guy doing almost same project as I did. Here is the link: [temperature jquery flot](http://scouris.wordpress.com/2010/09/10/temperature-sensing-with-arduino-php-and-jquery/#more-27)

In the flot code, I replaced some code with data I wanted to put into .(only two place I replace, without getting php value to make it easy) like

```
var dat = [ [123456789, 20.9],[1234654321, 22.1] ];
yaxis: { min: 20, max: 20>, tickFormatter: function (v, axis) { return v.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals) +"°C " }},
```

Here is the code:   Nothing happen when I display the html page. Please help !!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>Flot For Project</title>  



    <script src="jquery.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="jquery.flot.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.pack.js"></script><![endif]-->  

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.time.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.symbol.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.colorhelpers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.crosshair.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fillbetween.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.image.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.navigate.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>




    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  

     $(function () {
    var dat = [ [123456789, 20.9],[1234654321, 22.1] ];
    var options = {
      xaxis: { mode: "
    time ", timeformat: " % h: % M % d. % m. % y ", labelWidth: "
    10 " },
      series: {
      lines: { show: true, fill: true, fillColor: "
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)" },
      points: { show: true, fill: false },
      shadowSize: 5,
      color: "
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)"
    },
    grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
    yaxis: { min: 20, max: 20>, tickFormatter: function (v, axis) { return v.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals) +"°C " }},
    selection: { mode: "
    x ", color: "
    rgba(125, 0, 0, 0.6)" },
    legend: { show: true, position: "
    se ", backgroundOpacity: 0.4, backgroundColor: "
    rgb(255, 255, 255)", labelBoxBorderColor: "
    rgb(0, 0, 0)"},
  };
  var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder "),
  [ { data: dat, label: "
    Study Temp ", color:"
    #333"} ], options);
  var overview = $.plot($("#overview"), [{
        data: dat,
        label: "Min: °C, Max: °C",
        color: "#333"
    }], {
        series: {
            color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
            lines: {
                show: true,
                lineWidth: 1,
                fill: true,
                fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)"
            },
            shadowSize: 0
        },
        xaxis: {
            ticks: [],
            mode: "time"
        },
        yaxis: {
            ticks: [],
            min: 0,
            autoscaleMargin: 0.1
        },
        selection: {
            mode: "x",
            color: "rgba(125,0,0,0.6)"
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            position: "se",
            backgroundOpacity: 1,
            backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
            labelBoxBorderColor: "rgb(0,0,0)"
        }
    });
    $("#placeholder").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
        plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [dat],
        $.extend(true, {}, options, {
            xaxis: {
                min: ranges.xaxis.from,
                max: ranges.xaxis.to
            }
        }));
        overview.setSelection(ranges, true);
    });
    $("#overview").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
        plot.setSelection(ranges);
    });
    var humanTime;
    var jstime;

    function showTimes(t) {
        var datum = new Date(parseFloat(t));
        humanTime = datum.toUTCString();
    }

    function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
        $('
' + contents + '

').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            display: 'none',
            top: y + 25,
            left: x + 0,
            border: '2px solid #777',
            padding: '2px',
                'font-family': 'Arial',
                'font-size:': '1.2em',
                'font-weight': 'bold',
                'background-color': '#ddd',
            opacity: 0.80
        }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
    }
    var previousPoint = null;
    $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
        $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
        $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));
        if (item) {
            if (previousPoint != item.datapoint) {
                previousPoint = item.datapoint;
                $("#tooltip").remove();
                var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(0),
                    y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
                showTimes(x);
                showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                y + "°C (at " + humanTime + "+1000)");
            }
        } else {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            previousPoint = null;
        }
    });
    });

    </script>  
    </head >

        <body>  

    <div id="placeholder" style="height:400px;width=400px;">  

    </div>  

    <p>Flot Temperature realtime update.</p>  

    </body>  
    </html>
```

Comment: I just comment, this is not a real answer. Just to be sure, have you seen that the "max" value has a ">" character at the end (`max: 20>` in the `yaxis` definition)? Is it a copy/paste problem?

Comment: [18:20:21.601] TypeError: $.plot is not a function @ file:///User/renren/flot/projectFlot.html:46

Comment: $.plot is a JQuery Flot function as you know, so it seems that the jquery.flot.js was not loaded correctly, so please be sure that it resides in the directory where this code resides and that it has this name.

Comment: Why are you including jQuery and Flot twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formulate my answer here based on the comments.
First of all fix the "20>" value in the `yaxis` definition, then be sure that all the javascript files are in the same directory as the projectFlot.html file, and then that all the names correspond.
Another thing is that you are importing jquery.flot.js and jquery.js TWICE!
so remove the last line `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>` and even the second `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>`.

Comment: I am trying to get data my database, I should include another insert.php into my projectFlot.html. Am I?

Comment: Are you good at Arduino? I am getting the value out of arduino and put it into mysql. No one seem to answer that . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128437/getting-data-from-arduino-and-stored-in-database-through-ethienet